# how to integrate payment gateway with website created in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, payment-gateway

I want to integrate a payment gateway with Soho Hotel Theme using wordpress.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: That means that you already have a payment gateway wich means the documentation must be with it ! Did you read it ?

Comment: yes . i have the documentation and a PHP kit which can be used in a website that is created in PHP. but i wanted to know is there any special kind of framework used in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely want to integrate it as a WordPress plugin: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin This way you're extending the functionality without modifying the core. You could also potentially create custom page templates in your theme to integrate the gateway.

That said, the gateway is only part of the equation. Generally there's a cart or at least a purchase button on a page to place an order. Any third party cart should already have options to use gateways thus negating the need for you to build your own gateway integration. You need something that will collect the data and submit it to the gateway. If you haven't already solved that portion of the equation, solve that first.

Comment: do I have to design a plugin that gets and sends the values required by the payment gateway? Thank you

Comment: You need something that can get and send values to the gateway. You can design the plugin, or you can use one like http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/ or wp-ecommerce (I prefer woocommerce these days) and it will do it for you (provided your gateway is supported, which the major ones are.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting off with an e-commerce plugin like [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) - they have an [API](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/payment-gateway-api/) that you can use to get started. Thanks!